# Servlet 3.0 without web.xml error-page javaconfig

Tags: java, xml, spring, servlets, web.xml

In the `web.xml` file, error page as follows.

```
<error-page>
   <location>/WEB-INF/jsp/admin/ErrorPage.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

without `web.xml` javaconfig convert

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("sg.ani.api.controller")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
}
```

override search no error page

How to javaconfig convert?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class with the following:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandling {

  @ExceptionHandler(value=Exception.class)
  public String showErrorPage(){
    return "error";
  }
}
```

The @ControllerAdvice must be component-scanned so based on your config it must be somewhere in sg.ani.api.controller. This will catch all exceptions and direct them to the error page. So just create a new error page and you should be fine.