# Servlet Exception without web.xml

Tags: java, servlets, exception, web.xml

I have ExeptionServlet that catches the exceptions and displays the information what I need.

I point out in web.xml

```
<error-page>
<exception-type>javax.servlet.ServletException</exception-type>
<location>/exception</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
<exception-type>java.io.IOException</exception-type>
<location>/exception</location>
</error-page>
```

How to do without web.xml and Spring?

Comment: If you are using Servlets 3.0, than I'm afraid web.xml is required for defining error-page: [How to define <welcome-file-list> and <error-page> in servlet 3.0's web.xml-less?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13450154/5267892).

If you decide to use Spring Framework, you can do it as showed here: [Servlet 3.0 without web.xml error-page javaconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39440659/5267892)